# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined for Vue.js axios API call

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I am trying to get call a data source from a remote URL and always get this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`. The axios method is packed inside `axios.js`:

```
.....
result = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      axios.get(url)
        .then((response) => {
          const processedData = response.data.response.map((v) => {
            return v;
          })
          resolve(processedData);
        }).catch((error) => {
          if(typeof(error) == 'object'){
            alert(error) // @@@ I ALWAYS LAND HERE
          }
          reject(error.data); 
        });
    });
 ....
```

I have confirmed in my network console that the API url I am trying to access is working fine and all the data can be seen. The API format is following:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "alpha",
        "build_id": 50,
        "app_env_names": "",
        "app_env_list": [
            ""
        ],
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "feature/OPS-05",
        "build_id": 48,
        "image_tag": "feature_DEVOPS-605-jasc-cr-approval-test-71496674-48",
        "app_env_names": "dev",
        "app_env_list": [
            "dev"
        ],
       .....
```

I have tried remove map but it is not working. Does anyone know a way to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: I think you want `response.data.map()`, there is no `response` property in your data. You've also implemented the [explicit promise construction antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it), don't do that

Comment: Also, your `map()` call does nothing. Why even use it?

Comment: Thanks! I removed `removed` from the call and it works now. This is some third-party js I cannot modify cause there are some other job flows involved. I just defined my own API call.

Comment: Not sure what you mean but `response = axios.get(url).then(({ data }) => data)` would do the exact same thing

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I've updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Update**: Do not refer to the code below the line. It's clearly the promise construction anti pattern I wasn't aware of. So some edge cases might not be handled.

Use `response = axios.get(url).then(({ data }) => data)` Instead.

================================================================

Just found out seconds after I posted this question lol(& as @Phil has pointed out). Since there is no `response` in the call, simply removing it would do the trick:

```
result = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.get(url)
          .then((response) => {
            const processedData = response.data.map((v) => {
              return v;
            })
            resolve(processedData);
          }).catch((error) => {
            if(typeof(error) == 'object'){
              alert(error)
            }
            reject(error.data);
          });
      });
```